# Prove that the infinite-condition of the n by n Hilbert Matrix goes to infinity as n goes to infinity

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I need to prove that $cond_{\infty}(H_n) \rightarrow \infty$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ being

$$(H_n)_{ij}=\frac{1}{i+j-1}$$

the $n\times n$ Hilbert Matrix.
I know that
$$||H_n||_{\infty} = max(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k},\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k},...,\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{k})$$
but I don´t find a way to continue.

Well, I´m not even sure this is correct.

Comment: Well, presuming your calculation of $\|H_n\|_\infty$ is correct, you find that $S_n\leq \|H_n\|_\infty$ where $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n1/k$ is the $n$th partial sum of the harmonic series. What do you know about the harmonic series?

Comment: According to your formula $\|H_n\|_\infty =\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k}$